# Is there any way to prevent yourself from being in a populated list for Facebook invites?

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-games

I may play one at the most two games in Facebook. I really do not like getting those notifications that are invites for all those games I'll never play. I know the inviting is based on a populated list of one's friends that you can check/uncheck a checkbox. Is there any way to disable the ability to be seen in some/all game invites on facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You can make yourself disappear from invite list by blocking the game http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking

Block specific apps for which you don't want invites or if you have a SuperGamer friend on Facebook you can block them from sending you app invites.